# OKHttp3 POST Error : Internal Server Error Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, okhttp

I keep getting an internal server error 500 for this code.I am using a Rest web API. When i run the program it works but it does not send any data to the API. The response i get when i run the debugger is:
`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://192.168.1.250:5001/api/v1/job}`

The JSON test data I get is :
`{"id":"103","customer":{"id":31,"name":"ABC Poland"},"stops":{"Address":{"contact":{"name":"Play"}}},"references":{},"instructions":{"Value":"char"},"loads":{}}`

Here's the full AsyncTask class code i have more code but i think it would be pointless to add it in and harder for you guys to help me:

```
public class myNetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        int jobNoParam = jdb.getNextJobNo() - 1;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.250:5001/api/v1/job");
            js.put("id", String.valueOf(jobNoParam));

            JSONObject customerJSON = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject stopsJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject contactNameJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject referencesJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject instructionsJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject addressJson = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject loadsJson = new JSONObject();

            if (jdb.getCustomerName(jobNoParam) != null && !jdb.getCustomerName(jobNoParam).equals("")) {
                String idParam = jdb.getCustomerName(jobNoParam);
                int id = db.getCompanyId(idParam);
                customerJSON.put("id", id);
                customerJSON.put("name", jdb.getCustomerName(jobNoParam) );
            }

            Log.i("sendDataToServer", "First if!");
            if (jdb.getContactName(jobNoParam) != null && !jdb.getContactName(jobNoParam).equals("")) {
                contactNameJson.put("name", jdb.getContactName(jobNoParam));
            }

            Log.i("sendDataToServer", "Second if!");
            if (jdb.getJobType(jobNoParam) != null && jdb.getJobType(jobNoParam).equals("")) {
                instructionsJson.put("Title", jdb.getJobType(jobNoParam));
            }

            Log.i("sendDataToServer", "Third if!");
            if (jdb.getIssue(jobNoParam) != null && !jdb.getIssue(jobNoParam).equals("")) {
                instructionsJson.put("Value", jdb.getIssue(jobNoParam));
            }

            // Log.i("sendDataToServer", "Fourth if!");
            // js.put("Customer Name:", String.valueOf(customerJSON));

            js.put("customer", customerJSON);
            addressJson.put("contact", contactNameJson);
            stopsJson.put("Address", addressJson);
            js.put("stops", stopsJson);
            js.put("references", referencesJson);
            js.put("instructions", instructionsJson);
            js.put("loads", loadsJson);

            json = js.toString();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected Successfully",
            //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            doPostRequest(url, json);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
            protected Void onPostExecute () {
                return null;
            }

            public void doPostRequest (URL url,final String json){
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor())
                        .build();
                String credential = okhttp3.Credentials.basic(/*username*/, /*password */);
                final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, js.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", credential)
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            Log.d("TAG ------->", "Call Cancelled");
                            call.cancel();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            Log.d("TAG --------> onResponse:", response.body().string());
                            Log.d("JSON TAG ---------->", json);
                            Log.d("TAG Response Message ------>", response.message());
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snipped in your question is not very clear or helpful, because you are referencing variables which we can't see the definition in the code snippet that you have posted, but from what I can see `JSON` should be defined in the following way

`public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Your request body should look like this

```
final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
```

I suggest trying this :

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

as opposed to enqueue till you get a response from the server.

And finally check whether you are sending the correct data to your server with the correct headers